# concurrent access to several mysql tables

Tags: mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

I am using python. I want to access several mysql tables in one database using threads.

```
class DBThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def __init__(self,i,db):

        self.t = i
        self.DB=db
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):

        time.sleep(0)
        mpo = self.DB.get_place(self.t)

###################################################################

for i in range(0,3):

        dbThread = DBThread(self,i,self.db)
        dbThread.start()
        threads.append(dbThread)

        for dbThread in threads:
            dbThread.join()
```

but I got an error message

> Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during queryError 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during queryError 2006: MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Are you really looking for persistent connections? Or just parallel operations?